# Python | Pandas | Read Excel table with different format

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I've a excel file with the following format:

[image]

I'm trying read this table as a dataframe in order to get the following format:

```
Name, Age, Job
Peter, 25, Analyst
```

For that I am using the following code:

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name='Sheet1' ,index_col=False, header=0, squeeze=True)
```

I was thinking that the squeeze would solve it but I am getting Name and Peter as columns names :(

How can I resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did the answer help? :)

Comment: Sorry, only see the answer now :) Amazing! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transpose it like a matrix. In addition, set `index_col` to be `"Name"` if you don't want indexes.

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name='Sheet1' ,index_col="Name", header=0)

df = df.T
print(df)
```

```
Name   Age      Job
Peter   25  Analyst
```

See more from here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html